# Angular copying svg and webp files to main folder on build

Tags: angular, less, ng-build

When I build my Angular project, it is copying some svg and webp files from the assets folder to the main folder and renaming them. I noticed the files that were copying all are in the less (CSS).

How do I prevent the files from being copied and just use the originals?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the expected behavior for all files referenced in the CSS. Those files are copied to the main folder and fingerprinted. To avoid having 2 copies, store the files in a location other than the assets folder.